# Angular $watch doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a directive for drawing barcharts, and I'd like it to redraw the chart every time the data changes. I currently have this:

```
/* This directive will create a bar chart based on a dataTable. 
 * It expects the first column of the data table to contain the labels.
 * If more than 2 columns (labels plus more than one value) are supplied,
 * all bars generated by values in one row will be grouped together, making 
 * an easy visual comparison (benchmark).
 * If the option overlay is supplied, the odd value columns will be drawn
 * underneath the even values (Ex [label, col1, col2, col3, col4], with overlay = true will result 
 * in col1 and col3 to be drawn underneath col2 and col4
 */


angular.module('kapstok').directive('nBarChart', ['$window', '$location', '$parse', '$timeout', 
    function($window, $location, $parse, $timeout){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){

      // Read all the different parameters givin in the directive declaration.
      // If options are not given, they are replaced by their default values.
      var dataGetter        = $parse(attrs.data);
      var data = dataGetter(scope) || undefined;
      if(!data){
        throw Error("No (valid) data source specified!");
      }



          // Redraw the table once the table gets updated. However, usually multiple elements
      // of the table will be updated at the same time, while the watch will get triggered 
      // at each update. To prevent this, we give it a timeout of half a second,
      // allowing all the updates to be applied before the table is redrawn.
      scope.$watch(function(){ return data.getVersion(); }, $timeout(drawChart, 500));
```

Then, in my controller I do:

```
controlmodule.controller('PrefscanController',['$http', '$scope', 'DataTable', function($http, $scope, DataTable){
  $scope.myData = new DataTable();
  $scope.myData.addColumn("string", "label");
  $scope.myData.addColumn("number", "survey");
  $scope.myData.addColumn("number", "benchmark");
  $scope.myData.addColumn("number", "break-it");

  $scope.myData.addRow(['test', 20, 10, 4]);
  $scope.myData.addRow(['test2', 42, 13, 2]);


  $scope.hideBenchmark = function(){
    console.log("myData.version = ", $scope.myData.getVersion());
    $scope.myData.hideColumn(2);
    console.log("myData.version = ", $scope.myData.getVersion());
  }
```

In all the functions from dataTable, whenever anything is changed a property called 'version' is incremented, which is what I want the $watch to look at.

In my template I then have a button with an ng-click, which calls the hideBenchmark function. This function does get called, the dataTable version is updated, but whatever I try, the watch will not get triggered.

I've tried called $scope.$appy()/$scope.$digest() in my hideBenchmark function, tried adding 'true' to the watch (looking for object inequality), tried watching 'attrs.data', 'data.version' and none of it seem to trigger the watch! I know I can create another variable on the scope independent from this data one, watch that and change it every time I change the data, but that seems ugly and unnecessary.

Does anybody know WHY the watch doesn't get triggered, and how I can get it to do what I want?

Regards,

Linus

Comment: Have you tried putting "data" on the scope of your directive instead of getting it out of the attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Sunil, you should put it in the scope:

```
scope: {
    data: '='
}
```

Because if you do not do it, the data is not updated within the directive.

Here the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0t4z02yw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function invocation to the $watch, it should be a reference or a declaration, I think.

```
  scope.$watch(function(){ 
      return data.getVersion(); 
  }, function(){ 
      $timeout(drawChart, 500)
  });
```

Obviously, `drawChart` should be defined in that context for this to work... what you can try to see if the $watcher is being triggered is logging the value of the version.

```
  scope.$watch(function(){ 
      return data.getVersion(); 
  }, function(v){ 
      console.log(v)
  });
```

Note: For all the other responses saying you need to add it to the scope, that's false. You don't need to do that because you're passing your own custom function to the $watcher. The way you obtain your 'data' element is fine, with the `$parse` service.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it doesn't currently work is because nothing makes the outer scope (controller) notifying the inner scope (directive) that it should digest - that is something has been changed.
This happens because the data object is not part of the directive scope.
Couple of ways to deal with it:
First, you can pass the data object to the directive and create an isolated scope:

```
scope: {data: '='}
```

Or you can pass a function pointer to be notified when the data changed (hideBenchmark) in your case:

```
scope: {hideBenchmark: '@'}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f) is a plunker for the first method.